# spark-structured steaming not displaying any data in "format("memory")

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

When i do below it is working fine

```
company_info_df.select(col("value"))
             .writeStream()
              .outputMode("append")
              .option("truncate", false)
              .format("console")
              .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("4 seconds"))
              .start();
```

But when I do as below i.e. ".format("memory") , it is not showing anything

```
company_info_df.select(col("value"))
             .writeStream()
              .outputMode("append")
              .option("truncate", false)
              .format("memory")
              .queryName("company_info")
              .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir + "\\console")
              .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("4 seconds"))
              .start();

        Dataset<Row> company_inf = sparkSession.sql("select * from company_info");

        company_inf.show();
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
what is the correct way for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the below code in spark-shell that works for a sample data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};

val userSchema = new StructType().add("col1", "string").add("col2", "string").add("col3", "string").add("col4", "string").add("col5", "string").add("col6", "integer")
val csvDF = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).csv("/user/Temp") //reads the stream as source files in a folder.
csvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("abcd");
val dbDf2 = spark.sql("select col2, sum(col6) from abcd group by col2");
dbDf2.writeStream.queryName("abcdquery").outputMode("complete").format("memory").start()
```

In your code, try removing some of the options during write operation and see what is going wrong.